# jeasyui - Validating combobox input

Tags: combobox, jquery-easyui

I am using jeasyui editable combobox. How to restrict the user to type only valid values.

for example, if my list is containing,

- C
- Cplus
- Java

if the user type vb and tries to save, its saving with value "0".

Answer (score 0):

You can set the combobox as a **validatebox**. And define your rule to validate.
for more info, please hit [easyui validate box](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/validatebox.php)